# bokeh issue - Uncaught Error: SlickGrid's 'enableColumnReorder = true' option requires jquery-ui.sortable module to be loaded

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh

So, i had a working report, using bokeh and some Select buttons with callbacks using CustomJS.
(if its important, I have a simple DataTable, which I change the data according to the selected value in the Select button)

My bokeh version was 0.12.5 and everything worked ok.
Since upgrading to 1.3.0, the report is broken.

Looking at the source, this is the error I'm seeing:

bokeh-tables-1.3.0.min.js:86 Uncaught Error: SlickGrid's 'enableColumnReorder = true' option requires jquery-ui.sortable module to be loaded

Tried looking for solutions online, couldn't find anything.

Anyone have any idea? Do I need to load sortable module somehow?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the JavaScript console, you should've received this warning: `jquery-ui is required to enable DataTable.reorderable`. So yes, you have to load `jquery-ui` yourself.